# get name of hitTestPoint child

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I got a media clip called point with multiple child graphics. When my char hit a child i want to get the name or the child number of that graphic

```
if (point.hitTestPoint(char.x + 20,char.y + 30,true)){
    //name of child hit
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can brute this by hit testing the children in the container. Something like...

```
if (point.hitTestPoint(char.x + 20,char.y + 30)) {
  for(var n:int = 0; n < point.numChildren; n++) {
    if(point.getChildAt(n).hitTestPoint(char.x + 20,char.y + 30,true)) {
      // Do something. Store name, whatever
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't the most optimal method, but is simple and matches how you are currently doing it. If you are doing this for a game at high speed, then you would want to look into some kind of spatial partitioning to optimise your test.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to leave the last true on. I have updated the answer. Doing pixel checking is expensive so the intent was to do the box check first.

Comment: Why the down vote on this? Completely valid solution, imho. The outer hittest should stay as well (what to make all the heavy counting for if there is no hit on the parent clip?)